# Does a C++ object's destructor get called if there is an outstanding shared_ptr to one of its member functions?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, shared-ptr, destruction

Let's say we have the following class:

```
Class MyClass
{
    void func();
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> getFuncPointer(); // returns pointer to func()
};
```

Let's say there is an object of some other class (let's call it `objectB`) that owns a `shared_ptr` to an object (`objectA`) of type `MyClass`. Assume `objectB` is the only owner/user of `objectA` and no one else has access to `objectA`.

What happens in the following sequence:

1. `objectB` calls `objectA->getFuncPointer()` and stores the returned `shared_ptr`.
2. `objectB` calls `objectA.reset()`

Question: Does `objectA`'s destructor get called?

If `objectB` did *not* have the `shared_ptr` to one of `objectA`'s methods, the answer will obviously be yes.

What I am not sure of is the effect of `objectB` acquiring a `shared_ptr` to one of `objectA`'s *methods*.

If the answer is **YES**:

If `objectA` gets destructed, but another thread is still in `func()` via the function pointer, then what happens if we access a member variable? Seems problematic because `objectA` is gone along with its members.

If the answer is **NO**:

Seems problematic since I don't see how a `shared_ptr` to a member function can possibly keep the entire object alive. The function pointer knows nothing about the encompassing object, right?

Both scenarios seem problematic so that's why I am not sure which is the correct answer.

Comment: Please show a [mre], how are you forming you're `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES: an object can and will be deleted even if there's a `std::shared_ptr` that indirectly relies on it. By creating a `std::shared_ptr` to a given object (in this case a function), you're keeping that object around as long as it has a shared owner, so you have to promise that the object is valid for that long. If you break that promise, things will go wrong.

It's not really any different from having an object *O*<sub>1</sub> that holds a pointer to an object *O*<sub>2</sub>, and then `delete`-ing *O*<sub>2</sub> while *O*<sub>1</sub> is still around. Even if *O*<sub>1</sub> itself is held via `std::shared_ptr`, that doesn't preserve *O*<sub>2</sub>.

---

> Both scenarios seem problematic so that's why I am not sure which is the correct answer.

Unlike many languages, C++ makes no attempt to be "safe". It's very easy to write code that invokes *[undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*; an important part of working in C++ is avoiding doing so. `std::shared_ptr` is a tool to *help* you write *safe* code, but it doesn't *stop* you from writing *unsafe* code.

---

> What I am not sure of is the effect of `objectB` acquiring a `shared_ptr` to one of `objectA`'s *methods*.

There's actually no such thing as a `shared_ptr` to a method. In your case, you have a `shared_ptr` to an instance of `std::function<void()>`. An instance of `std::function` holds a callable object (its "target"), but the `shared_ptr` itself doesn't know anything about that target, doesn't own it, and can't/won't keep it alive.

Additionally, although an instance of `std::function` *can* hold a pointer to a member function, that can't be the situation in your case, because a pointer to a member function takes the `this` pointer as an argument, rather than implicitly depending on a specific instance; so if that were what you have, it would be a `std::function<void(MyClass*)>` rather than a `std::function<void()>`, and it wouldn't care if any particular instance of `MyClass` had been deleted. Rather, your `std::function` probably holds the result of a lambda expression, and that lambda probably holds a pointer to your instance of `MyClass`. If so, then that's not an *owning* pointer, so, again, it won't keep the instance alive.

Some docs you might want to look at:

- `std::function`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
- Pointers to member functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions
- Lambda expressions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: Thanks. If the answer is YES, meaning if objectA gets destructed, what happens to the memory associated with the member function? The function pointer is still valid so I am assuming that function is still defined and callable for anyone who has access to the shared_ptr? But the destruction of objectA would clean up all its members in memory, right? So how can it be callable? It seems contradictory.

Comment: @FuadHossain: In C++, there's no contradiction between "the compiler will let you call the function" and "the function can massively misbehave because it's referencing a deleted object".

Comment: Right. I knew this generally speaking, but for some reason I thought having a shared_ptr to a member function (as opposed to a dumb pointer) would keep the object alive. I guess not!

Comment: @FuadHossain: I see. I think what you're missing is that you don't *really* have a shared_ptr to a member function; you have a shared_ptr to an instance of std::function (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and that instance of std::function presumably holds a pointer to your instance of MyClass. So you're keeping the instance of std::function alive, but its internal pointer is a dumb pointer, and doesn't keep your instance of MyClass alive. Does that make sense?

Comment: @FuadHossain: When you pass a pointer to `std::shared_ptr`, you're telling it "I own the object that this points to, and now I want you to take ownership of it for me". In your example of "objectB has a shared_ptr to a member variable living in objectA", it sounds like someone has lied to shared_ptr, telling it that it owned an object, when in reality that object was a sub-object of an object that was going to go away soon. That's undefined behavior. (It would actually be undefined behavior even if objectA *didn't* go away soon: shared_ptr will try to `delete` something it doesn't own!)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I deleted my comment once I thought about it (before seeing your reply)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely yes, it gets deleted as per the details give by @ruakh above.

But there is one possible way for object A to extend it's own lifetime via the `getFuncPointer` invoked by object B or elsewhere.  And that is if the std::function returned by getFuncPointer is capturing the instance itself.

Consider this implementation using enable_shared_from_this

```
class MyClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>
{
public:
    void func();

    std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> getFuncPointer()
    {
        auto spThis = shared_from_this(); // get a shared_ptr to "this"

        auto fn = [spThis]() {   // capture spThis by value increases yet another ref on the shared_ptr
            spThis->func();
        };

        auto result = std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>();
        *result = fn;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Then if you have this implementation

```
    auto a = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    auto spFunc = a->getFuncPointer();
    a.reset();
    (*spFunc)();
```

The `a.reset()` call above will reduce the shared_ptr's reference count by 1, but there's still another outstanding reference captured within spFunc.  object `a` will ultimately be deleted when `spFunc` goes out of scope and releases its captured variables.

Comment: This is quite insightful. Thanks @selbie

Answer (score 1):

Member functions/methods are usually implemented in compilers as global functions with an extra first parameter receiving the instance of the object, so a `std::function <void()>` 's type would in reality be `void (MyClass&)`/`void (MyClass*)` when referencing a method function of `MyClass` [which is why when you try to create an `std::bind` for a member function, you pass in the object instance as the first parameter as well].

by returning a `shared_ptr` of a `std::function<void()>`, you are basically constructing a `shared_ptr` containing `std::function<void(this)>` for &MyClass::func(), which holds no actual ownership over the instance, so the answer is **YES**, that `shared_ptr` should not prevent the destruction of the object.

EDIT:
just saw your other comment, as i said the methods are functions like other free functions, they reside in the **CODE** section of the process's memory, they don't occupy **DATA** memory, so they are not associated with object's lifespan, a single copy of them (under normal scenarios per each translation unit) will be present there whether you create 1 `MyClass` object or 10000 of `MyClass` objects, so they are callable in the entirety of runtime of the program

Comment: Thanks! So I gather then that even though it is callable, since the implicit "this" is now gone, we would get undefined behavior if we attempt to access any member variables from within func(), for example.

Comment: precisely, think of methods as gateways requiring an extra 'ticket', the ticket would point towards associated data. If there are no people with tickets going through the gateway, the gateway would be still there, from the program's start to the end. If your ticket's invalid, you can't go through or you get pointed towards undefined memory. you can cast a 0x00000 pointer to your `MyClass` and pass it as the instance, you can call the methods, but it will result in errors + exception and undefined behavior.